# Add Infusionsoft Subscription Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on woocommerce site in which i can send orders to infusionsoft but I have created a product as subscription and i want when user buy this product it should be added as subscription on infusionsoft. for send order to infusionsoft I am using api to pass the order data but dont know how to send subscription or any woocommerce plugin available to add woocommerce product to subscription then please let me know. Below is the code to send order to infusion:-

````
$p_desc=$product->get_short_description();
$p_desc=str_replace(array("'",'"'),'', $p_desc);
if(strpos($p_desc,'<') !== false){
    $p_desc=$title;
}
$products[$p_id]=array('name'=>$title,'desc'=>$p_desc,'price'=>$unit_price,'sku'=>$sku,'quantity'=>$qty);

        
} }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different ways you could handle this.

1. Use Infusedwoo plugin to make the connection between Woocommerce and Infusionsoft. https://woo.infusedaddons.com/features.html
2. Use the api like you are to create an order and then use a product purchase goal in a campaign to start a sequence that runs an action set. Create an action set to Create an Order and then add a subscription to the action set.
3. Using the api to create a subscription. https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/E-Commerce/createOrderItemsOnOrderUsingPOST